# sliding up/down form in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a from with sliding up/down animation in a bootstrap template.

Here is the code : http://bootply.com/94382

When You click on the `add` button, the form will slide down and when You will click it again, it will slide up.

But if i am adding new elements on the page after the buttons, the new elements are not moving down instead the form is coming over the elements.

i want to achieve that the new elements will slide down and then form will come. But this is not happening now. Please help me out.

Comment: You have a lot of problems on your menu with the use of `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `position:absolute`, `position:fixed` from your css where it actually not required. Also, use spans or ul li list with proper styles to render the icons, buttons, images in `<div id="bottom-header">`. Then remove `position:absolute` from your form and give proper margins width etc. so that you will get what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `#sliding_form` CSS properties to :

```
#sliding-form {
    display: none;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 45%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Updated Bootply](http://bootply.com/97384)